# Find all pizza delivery restaurants whose service area my users are within

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, gis, geospatial

I'm working on a project that requires some geo stuff, which I haven't used until now (which I'm a bit sad about, it's pretty sweet). Anyways, hit a wall and looking for advice from the experts on how best to proceed. Here's the problem:

So let's say I have a list of pizza delivery restaurants. Each one has a physical location [lng, lat] and a deliveryRadius in miles. I need to provide my users the ability to find all pizza delivery restaurants whose deliveryRadius they are in.

We're using mongo/mongoose with a node.js server if that makes a difference. Here's the query (that doesn't work; but might provide more insight into what I need to do).

propertyCoordinates = [lng, lat] of user, stored like this:

```
coordinates: {
   type: {type: String, default: 'Point'},
   coordinates: {type: [Number], default: [1, 1]},
}
```

Query:

```
try {
    const vendors = await Vendor.find({}, { _id: 0, serviceRadius: 1 });
    const serviceRadiusValues = vendors.map((vendor) => vendor.serviceRadius);
    const aggregatedVendors = await Vendor.aggregate([{
        $geoNear: {
            near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: propertyCoordinates },
                distanceField: 'distance',
                spherical: true,
                maxDistance: { $multiply: [{ $max: serviceRadiusValues }, 1609.34] },
        },
    }]);
    console.log("list: ", aggregatedVendors);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error with stuff here:", error);
  }
```

I've tried this:

```
      try {
        const vendors = await Vendor.find();
        const aggregatedVendors = await Vendor.aggregate([{
            $addFields: {
                maxDistance: {
                    $multiply: ['$serviceRadius', 1609.34],
                },
            },
        },
        {
            $match: {
                'physicalLocation.coordinates': {
                    $geoWithin: {
                        $centerSphere: [
                            propertyCoordinates,
                            { $divide: ['$maxDistance', 3959] },
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
        }]);
  
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error with stuff here:", error);
    }
```

And

```
  try {
    const vendorsWithinServiceArea = await Vendor.find({
        'physicalLocation.coordinates': {
            $geoWithin: {
                $centerSphere: [
                    propertyCoordinates,
                    { $divide: ['$serviceRadius', 3959] },
                ],
            },
    }})
    console.log("list: ", vendorsWithinServiceArea)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error with stuff here:", error)
  }
```

I've tried a few variations of this, but the issue is that I can't use a "dynamic" field inside geoWithin. And because each restaurant has its own deliveryRadius, I'm a bit stuck. I can hack my way through this, but I want to do it right. Somebody recommended elasticSearch, so I'm going to look into using it to solve this, but not positive it can do what I need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with MongoDB, but that's a common issue with all geospatial databases. The geospatial filter wants to use spatial index to find the relevant rows. But it is impossible to use index based on locality if you have to check each row's service radius. The database must assume there might be a row 1000 miles away with 2000 miles service radius, so it has to check everything.

I can think of two approaches to this query:

1. Assume some maximum service radius. You can check the database, and find the maximum radius, they probably don't vary too much. Say it is 50 miles. Then search all pizza places within 50 miles.  It is not perfect use of index, and it will bring places outside their service radius. In `geoNear` query, you've added `distanceField`, now do another filter for places where `distance` computed by `geoNear` less than place's `serviceRadiusValues`.

If the service radiuses are reasonably uniform, this should perform really well.

2. Add service area polygon to each place. I don't know if MongoDB syntax, but most geospatial databases have [`ST_Buffer`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_buffer) or similar function that builds a polygon around given geometry. Add a field to each place with service area polygon, by buffering their location with their service area. Now you can index this new field, and do spatial filter where this service area intersects the user's location.

I would use this approach in cases where the service radiuses vary a lot (unlikely in this case), and the first approach has to use too large search radius. It is also the way to go if the service area is defined by say driving distance, rather than "as-the-crow-flies" distance, and is more complex than a circle.

Comment: MongoDB offers [POLYGON](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/geojson/#geojson-objects).  You should be able to programmatically create something like a hexagon or octagon with the appropriate radius centered on the store location, store that in vendor document and you should be able to use a simple geoIntersets.  I don't know of any delivery operation that defines their area in terms of a static straight-line radius, usually it is based on drive distance or time, so polygon is probably a better fix in the long term.